# determine the name of the executing script

Tags: haskell

In haskell how would I go about getting and printing out the name of the executing script?
Also since I'm here when I use some code to list directory contents and print them out at the console (GHCi) I just get the following result "[]" from my knowledge of other languages i would assume it's because it returns an array but then print should print the array anyway, no?

this is on windows

Answer (score 6):

I think `getProgName` from `System.Environment` should do that but you should check how portable it is on windows.

`"[]"` is the empty list. You can use `getDirectoryContents` from `System.Directory`.

```
Prelude System.Directory> getDirectoryContents "."
["hist","parse.hs","b.hs","d.hs","qsort.hs"]
```

Comment: when I use getProgName the output is "<interactive>"

Comment: Yeah cause you are using that in ghci. Try using it in a haskell program which you compile and run.

Answer (score 5):

The [`System.Environment`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html) module is used to access information about the system environment, such as [`getProgName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v:getProgName) which returns the name of the executable.

The result `[]` is an empty list, so it seems you are trying to list the contents of an empty directory.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned getProgName should do the trick for you. If you're unfamiliar with the I/O functions of haskell I would suggest reading about it in a book such as Learn You a Haskell for Great Good. It has a pretty nice chapter on I/O including command line arguments. see http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#command-line-arguments